# Get the negative of a base64 image

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

I have a base64 image. I need to get the negative of that. 
The exact code is:

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
```

I am using jsPDF to get the image in the PDF. I cannot use the `context.getImageData(....)` because, jsPDF only has functions that work with base64 image data.

If that is not possible, please suggest a way to convert the base64 to image pixel data, then find the negative of that and again convert back to base64 image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you call `canvas.toDataURL`, you can invert the colors of the image on the canvas itself using a *difference* composite operation:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'difference';
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Optional: restore the image on the canvas
ctx.restore();
```